# HoverIntent only fires once

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I've been using HoverIntent to show a popup menu and the code below works for one time only.

I need the `#MenuPopup` to stay visible while the user is hovered over it, so I used `clearTimeout(MenuButton.hoverIntent_t);` to stop the `hideMenu()` function from calling and then called `hideMenu()` when the user is no longer hovering over `#MenuPopup`. This works.

If I now mouseover `#MenuButton` again `#MenuPopup` does not show. Any ideas why?

Thank you in advance.

Barry

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#MenuButton").hoverIntent({
        over: showMenu, 
        timeout: 1000, 
        out: hideMenu
});

$("#MenuPopup").hover(
  function () {
    clearTimeout(MenuButton.hoverIntent_t);
  }, 
  function () {
    setTimeout("hideMenu()",1000);  
  }
);  

}); // close document.ready

function showMenu() {  
    $("#MenuPopup").animate({ 
    top: "-195px",
    height: "195px"
  }, 500, "swing" );
}

function hideMenu() { 
    $("#MenuPopup").animate({ 
         top: "0px",
         height: "0px"
        }, 200, "swing" );
}
```

Comment: Was this a really badly worded question? Maybe it didnt make any sense. I'd be interested to know - Thank you.